# How to download transformed data from Jupyter notebook (not the original data files) into .csv format?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, save

Imported libraries:

```py
import pandas as pd             # For data manipulation and analysis
import seaborn as sns           # For visualization
import numpy as np              # For numerical operations
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # For data visualization
import plotly.express as px     # For interactive visualizations
import warnings                 # For filtering and ignoring warnings
```

Loaded data into pandas DataFrames:

```
schools_df = pd.read_csv('Schools.csv')                       
students_df = pd.read_csv('Students.csv') 
# + other 10
```

3. Identified & addressed the dataset’s data quality issues
4. How do I now transfer all 12 transformed data frames separately from Jupyter into 12 `.csv` files?

Thanks a lot!

Tried to save as .py but it would save all jupyter file as one including text, not the transformed data

Comment: Please wrap your code in backticks to have proper formatting. Here is a backtick: `
You can wrap it between 2 (1+1) backticks if it's a short code, or 6 (2*3) backticks if you want to submit multiple lines. This later one also allows you to define the language you are using. for example: ```python

Comment: You can use pandas' `to_csv` method to save a dataframe as a csv: `df.to_csv('data.csv')`.

Comment: "You can use pandas' to_csv method to save a dataframe as a csv: df.to_csv('data.csv')". – 
Thank you very much ambrustorok! That solved my problem! Great advice!

Comment: ambrustorok - thanks again! Your other solution worked just fine, so I haven't had a chance to try this one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.